# Why I can't use my flutter app as a server?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, server

I want to use my app as a server so other people can connect to my app.
I made a server in my flutter app, but I can't manage to access my server from any other device, I want my server to be public, but I keep having "refused connection"...

here's my function to start the server:

```
startServer() async {
    var server = await HttpServer.bind(
        InternetAddress.anyIPv4, 8080);
    await for (var request in server) {
      request.response
        ..headers.contentType =
            new ContentType("text", "plain", charset: "utf-8")
        ..write('Hello, world')
        ..close();
    }
  }
```

Here is my guess of why I can't access my server:

- The IP address is wrong, I tried with many other IP address, always resulting in errors
- The IP isn't public
- Android won't let an app open a port
- I missed a manipulation to do in order to make it work

Tested with an emulated Pixel 2 API 30 and a real phone (Xiaomy Mimix 2), Flutter 2.0.3, Kotlin 1.3.50

I hope you have ideas about how to help me solve my problem, and ask if I missed any information.
Thank you.

Comment: What permissions do you have set for your application in your manifest? You might be missing some network related ones.

Comment: Hello, here is a list of all the permissions I seted:
- CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
- ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
- ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
- CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE
- INTERNET
- ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
- ACCESS_WIFI_STATE